# How to pass prop's value into another prop of the same element in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-props

I am trying to pass the value of component's prop into another prop to style it, as below:

```
<Component propOne={true} style={{ backgroundColor: propOne ? "red" : "blue" }} >  
</Component>
```

Here propOne inside style prop is undefined.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as written - you can only directly access a component's props from within that component. I think you have two options:

1. Define `style` inside the body of `Component`. If you control `Component`, this is the easiest way.
2. Assign `propOne`'s value to a const, and use it in both props.